# How to achieve one way referencing in swift closures

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, closures, nsoperation, weak-references

I try to encapsulate most of my async activity in operations, and often I have operations that launch other operations, etc...

The problem that I'm facing is that when I reference the original operation it can get deallocated before the successive ops can finish. The closures I use fail if I have a `weak self`, `weak me = self` or *(disastrously)* `unowned me = self` in place; but if I use `self` without them, neither op deallocates (memory leak).

**Is it possible to keep a reference alive from within a closure, without creating a two way, circular reference situation?**

Answer (score 0):

First all you will need to ask yourself whether your `self` is going to be nil in future or not. If yes then `weak` and `unowned` comes in picture.

The safe way to do is use `weak` and then check whether it has been deallocated or not.

```
  your-closure { [weak self] in
      guard let strongSelf = self else {
          print("self is been deallocated")
          return
      }
  }
```

When the closure runs in above case, it will only capture `weak self`. At the instant the closure starts up, `weak self` is either `self`, or it’s nil. You can test to see if `strongSelf` is set or not.

If `weak self` is equal to `self`, then `strongSelf` retains it, and it stays retained until the closure returns when it's released. It’s all or nothing.

Comment: I get that. My question is about the 'if no' part of your response. What if I'm trying to prevent self from being nil in the future without permanently allocating it in memory? Because I'm using ops, they will run out and terminate unless I create a perm link, but I'm asking if there's a way to avoid that.

Comment: I want the original operation to hangout until I'm done with it, then be able to release it.

Comment: @JamesLingo in that case you will have to keep hold of `operation` using strong self. There is no other choice here. Only thing will happen is lifetime of self will be extended in this case up until after the block finishes. Also Note that the block gets eventually executed, no matter whether the `Self` is still alive or has been deallocated in the mean time.

Comment: Also to clarify, a retain cycle will only happen if you will some property referencing closure and then closure is capturing `self` but I don't see this in your case. Hope it clarifies.

Comment: Doesn't that create performance issues over time: I'm using these ops a lot, and if the user doesn't quit their app for months wouldn't that start to add up? Does ARC have some way of garbage timing memory allocations that haven't been in use for a prolonged period?

Comment: Wait are you saying that after the closure executes the strong ref can be broken? I thought the ref kept both the op and the closure in memory?

Comment: No, I am saying when you have retained cycle then only you need `weak or unowned` unless you don't. Just to confirm, are storing operations are strong properties in class which are calling the operations?

Comment: Yes they're strong.